# dynamic routing on github pages with sveltekit

Tags: svelte, github-pages, sveltekit

I am experimenting with dynamic routing on static site hosting services like github pages. I understand that normally you wouldn't want to do this and may have to jump through hoops to get it working.

I am using `onMount` function from `svelte` to load the data on the client side. I have two dynamic urls, `/qna?id=1`, this works but the other url `/blog/[slug]` fails. When I navigate to a url like `/blog/hello`, it returns the following error in console: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://mohit2152sharma.github.io/_app/immutable/entry/start.a84ced15.js`. My guess is this being caused by some path issue. If anyone has encountered similar issue, would appreciate your help and time.

(You can check out the repo here: https://github.com/mohit2152sharma/svelte-mpa-example)

PS: I have followed almost all the steps mentioned in the docs, like setting up `csr=true` and `ssr=false`, using `adapter-static`, using `fallback='404.html'` which is same as that of github pages error page.

PPS: If I deploy the same project on vercel it works, the only changes I make while deploying are change the adapter to `adapter-vercel` and use the defaults for `adapter`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not configuring or using the repository as [`base` path](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths) correctly. The repository name is missing between domain and `_app` in the requested path:

```
https://mohit2152sharma.github.io/_app/immutable/entry/start.a84ced15.js
```

This much is noted in the [GitHub Pages specific docs](https://When%20building%20for%20GitHub%20Pages,%20make%20sure%20to%20update%20paths.base%20to%20match%20your%20repo%20name,%20since%20the%20site%20will%20be%20served%20from%20https://your-username.github.io/your-repo-name%20rather%20than%20from%20the%20root.):

> When building for GitHub Pages, make sure to update `paths.base` to match your repo name, since the site will be served from https://your-username.github.io/your-repo-name rather than from the root.

Also think there used to be something in the docs about issues around Jekyll and directories prefixed with `_`. By default, code ends up in `_app` as seen in the error and that was not be served. Maybe not an issue anymore.
Would disable Jekyll by putting a `.nojekyll` into the root of the pages branch and change the output directory ([`appDir`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#appdir)) to something different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to solve it by setting `paths.asset` in svelte config to my github.io url including repo name.